# Как убрать заголовок страницы в woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Столкнулся с тем, что нужно изменить системный заголовок страницы Checkout от woocommerce. Подскажите, в каком файле можно его отключить? Или поставить в другом месте?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce для страницы оформления заказа создает специальные сервисные страницы в "Страницах"

Вы можете скрыть заголовок через фильтр 'the_title'

Например так :

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'remove_checkout_page_title', 10, 2 );

function remove_checkout_page_title( $title, $id ) {
    
    if ( is_checkout() )  return '';
    
    return $title;
}
```